# Yeoman error launching project with "grunt" command

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I was following yeoman tutorial http://yeoman.io/codelab/prepare-production.html and everything worked fine until I tried to launch my project with "grunt" command then I got the following error:

```
Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) taskAutoprefixer's process() method is deprecated and will removed in next major release. Use postcss([autoprefixer]).process() insteadFile .tmp/styles/main.css created.
jit-grunt: Plugin for the "ngtemplates" task not found.If you have installed the plugin already, please setting the static mapping.See https://github.com/shootaroo/jit-grunt#static-mappings
Warning: Task "ngtemplates" failed. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

I use Linux Mint 17

Answer (score 2):

[A workaround](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1129) was posted at the generator-angular github.  Try modifying your Gruntfile.js to make the jit-grunt block look like this:

```
// Automatically load required Grunt tasks
require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
  useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
  ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
  cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn'
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me, so basically it just did not generate angularjs library binding, so I have to add it manually? Is this manual work required for all external libraries that I will load to my project such as backbone, sass etc ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a issue for [grunt-autoprefixer](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer) which is deprecated.

I am guessing, you installed a old version of generator-angular and current version of grunt which is written in the tutorial with following commands.

```
npm install --global yo bower grunt-cli
npm install --global generator-angular@0.11.1
```

It is better to install the current version of generator-angular. Just run this and start over again.

```
npm install -g generator-angular
```